ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils' npm install Angular with Python 2.x
I Am trying to install the Angular dependencies, but I have a trouble with Python versions. At the first, I have installed the Python version 2.6, and it shows me the next error:
npm ERR!     import gyp  # noqa: E402
npm ERR!     ^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Front\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp.input
npm ERR!   File "C:\Front\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 19, in <module>
npm ERR!     from distutils.version import StrictVersion
npm ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

And when I switch the version 3.6 and see the next error:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                                ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:400:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)

Do you know how can I proceed  with the installation and why the dependencies requires that?
I have installed bot versions of python (2.6 and 3.12) but it fails in both ways.

you shoudn't use python2, is deprecated

it's likely that one of your dependency are out of date, what version of angular are you trying to install?

It worked! I've change the angular versión and compiled fine, now the problem that I have is with some dependecies. The version deployed for the client is so old, I don't know the reason but it really worked the Link, Thank you so much
